# Godot Fade In Between Black and White Using Tween Delay Doesn't Work

Tags: godot, tween, gdscript

I am trying to switch in between 2 tween.interpolate_properties() depending on if the player is moving or not. However, the delay function does not work. Without delay on line 11, it works immediately (as it should). However, when i add a delay of 2 seconds, it looks like after two seconds it briefly flashes black (but not all the way) and then goes back to transparent. Attached is the code, please help!

```
extends Sprite
onready var TweenNode = get_node("../Tween")
onready var velocity

func _ready():
    modulate.a = 0

func _process(delta):
    velocity = get_node("../../").velocity
    if velocity == Vector2.ZERO:
        TweenNode.interpolate_property(self, "modulate", modulate, Color(0, 0, 0, 1), 5, Tween.TRANS_EXPO, Tween.EASE_OUT_IN, 2)
    else:
        TweenNode.interpolate_property(self, "modulate", modulate, Color(0, 0, 0, 0), .1, Tween.TRANS_EXPO, Tween.EASE_OUT_IN)
    TweenNode.start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case of "The computer is doing what you told it to".

This line:

```
TweenNode.interpolate_property(self, "modulate", modulate, Color(0, 0, 0, 1), 5, Tween.TRANS_EXPO, Tween.EASE_OUT_IN, 2)
```

It says, after 2 seconds set `modulate` to the value `modulate` has right now. *And then vary its value to `Color(0, 0, 0, 1)` in a span of 5 seconds, with such and such easing.*

And you are doing that every frame. So, after two seconds, every frame, it will set `modulate` to the value it had two seconds ago. *The interpolation will try to change `modulate`, just for the value to get reset next frame.*

Hence:

> it looks like after two seconds it briefly flashes black (but not all the way) and then goes back to transparent

If you leave it running, you will see that after other two seconds it does not go back to transparent. Instead it goes back to that slightly black you saw after two seconds. Because after four seconds, that is what modulate had two seconds ago.

And, as you can imagine, that means it will start to get a little darker. And after a few minutes minutes it will be pretty much black.

---

We could, of course, keep track of what `interpolate_property` call we have done. And to do that we would add a new property where we keep track of what value we told the `Tween` to interpolate to…

---

Well, I'm going to take a side step and explain [`follow_property`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_tween.html#class-tween-method-follow-property)!

With `follow_property` you can tell the `Tween` to interpolate a property to the value of another property.

So, we add our new property, for example:

```
var _modulate_target:Color
```

We need to initialize it, by the way:

```
func _ready():
    modulate.a = 0
    _modulate_target = modulate
```

And then we can tell the `Tween` to make make one property follow the other property:

```
_modulate_target = Color(0, 0, 0, 1)
TweenNode.follow_property(
    self,
    "modulate",
    modulate,
    self,
    "_modulate_target",
    5,
    Tween.TRANS_EXPO,
    Tween.EASE_OUT_IN,
    2
)
TweenNode.start()
```

And to avoid the reset behavior, we check the value of our new property, and if it is already the value we want, we do nothing:

```
if _modulate_target != Color(0, 0, 0, 1):
    _modulate_target = Color(0, 0, 0, 1)
    TweenNode.remove(self, "modulate")
    TweenNode.follow_property(
        self,
        "modulate",
        modulate,
        self,
        "_modulate_target",
        5,
        Tween.TRANS_EXPO,
        Tween.EASE_OUT_IN,
        2
    )
    TweenNode.start()
```

There I'm also removing any existing animation on `modulate` with:

```
TweenNode.remove(self, "modulate")
```

And you would follow that pattern for every change. I would argue for using [`setget`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#setters-getters), but given that you want different `duration` and `delay` that won't do. Instead we can simply wrap that into another `func`:

```
func _tween_modulate(target:Color, duration:float, delay:float) -> void:
    if _modulate_target == target:
        return

    _modulate_target = target
    TweenNode.remove(self, "modulate")
    TweenNode.follow_property(
        self,
        "modulate",
        modulate,
        self,
        "_modulate_target",
        duration,
        Tween.TRANS_EXPO,
        Tween.EASE_OUT_IN,
        delay
    )
    TweenNode.start()
```

And you use it like this:

```
    if velocity == Vector2.ZERO:
        _tween_modulate(Color(0, 0, 0, 1), 5, 2)
    else:
        _tween_modulate(Color(0, 0, 0, 0), .1, 0)
```

---

Please notice that you still need `_modulate_target` to check if it is different than `target`. However, yeah, sure you can use `interpolate_property`:

```
func _tween_modulate(target:Color, duration:float, delay:float) -> void:
    if _modulate_target == target:
        return

    _modulate_target = target
    TweenNode.remove(self, "modulate")
    TweenNode.interpolate_property(
        self,
        "modulate",
        modulate,
        target,
        duration,
        Tween.TRANS_EXPO,
        Tween.EASE_OUT_IN,
        delay
    )
    TweenNode.start()
```

Using `follow_property` just made this refactor easier to explain.

Comment: This is an amazing answer and in depth, thank you so much!